# Draggable and Resizable after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

How I can drag and resize element after drop.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".selectField").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone",

  });

  $("#fuller").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      draggable = draggable.clone();      
      draggable.appendTo("#fuller");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="panel">
    <div id="resizable" class="selectField">
        <label for="#input">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="input" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fuller"></div>
```

When I add `draggable()` and `resizable()` to dropped element it's does not work.
How I can resolve it?

Comment: You need to recall plugins once element dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the cloned draggable element as resizable once the drop is complete

```
$(function() {

  $(".selectField").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone",

  });

  $("#fuller").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      var dragged = draggable.clone();      
      dragged.appendTo("#fuller");
      dragged.resizable({containment: '#fuller'})
    }
  });
});

<div id="panel">
    <div id="resizable" class="selectField">
        <label for="#input">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="input" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fuller"></div>
```

Comment: how i can to make the cloned element as draggable inside #fuller div?
@vinayakj

Comment: I already added the code to the answer.. please have a look.. changed the names to make clearer

Comment: it working nice!
one more question. When i add this:dragged.draggable(); it does not work correctly.

Comment: It should actually..  still try with $('<any element tag>') instead of clone. I am currently working on exactly same thing.. where first I need to drag and drop the element and then within container it should be draggable and resizable

Comment: how can i add , draggable property to a new element drop without it clone iteself ?

Comment: instead of cloning, create new element and add draggable property to a newly created element.